# Karate send json body with GET Method

Tags: karate

I'm trying to send GET Request with Json Body.
When I try this codes it is adding to endpoint as a parameter or API response returning 404.
But I can send request in postman.

I tried 2 different code :

setup.createdModule => integer value ( 1,2,3 .. )

This is my background :

```
  Background:
    * url baseUrl
    * header content-type = 'application/json'
    * header Authorization = Token
    * header accept = 'application/json'
    * configure ssl = true
```

**First One :**

```
Scenario:  Feedback List
    Given path '/api/feedback_list/'
    And request { "module_id": #(setup.createdModule) }
    When method GET
    Then status 200
```

**Second One :**

```
Scenario:  Feedback List
    Given path '/api/feedback_list/'
    And form field module_id = setup.createdModule
    When method GET
    Then status 200
```

This 2 scenario is not working.

**Postman Response is 200 OK :**

[image: Postman Response]

How can I solve this in karate framework ?

Comment: please just upgrade